# Can you help me I want to print the value of factorial 4 but the following function is always giving NAN why?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, callback, nan

My question is about recursive function why it is showing always NAN instead of showing the value of factorial 4.

```
function factorial(i){
              if (i == 1) { return;}  
              return i * factorial(--i);};        
      console.log(factorial(4));
```

Comment: You don’t return anything in case `i` is `1`. `undefined * 2 * 3 * 4` is `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function factorial(i){
              if (i == 1) { return 1;}  
              return i * factorial(--i);};        
      console.log(factorial(4));
```

That right.

Answer (score 0):

`if (i == 1) { return;}`  you should return a number here like `return 1;`

```
function factorial(i){
              if (i == 1) { return 1;}  
              return i * factorial(--i);};        
      console.log(factorial(4));
```

small version of code:

```
const fact = (num) => num ==1 ? 1 : num * fact(--num);
```